# Docker MySQL does not popoulate database with data

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-workbench

I have following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
    services:
      storage:
        image: library/mysql:5.5
        environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=storage
        ports:
         - 3306:3306
        volumes:
         - ./mysql-initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
         - ./mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Inside docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory following .sql script:

```
BEGIN;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `storage`;
CREATE DATABASE `storage`;
USE `storage`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SETTINGS;
CREATE TABLE SETTINGS (
  `NAME` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`NAME`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO
`storage`.`SETTINGS` (`NAME`, `VALUE`)
VALUES
('AAAAA','BBBBB');

COMMIT;
```

When I executes `docker-compose up` I get information that .sql script is executed:

`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_storage_schema.sql`

When I connect to that database from MySQL Workbench I see only empty tables without data. It looks like INSERT statement was not executed.

I tried also:

1. Naming columns with and without "`" character
2. Using and not BEGIN/COMMIT

Comment: Note that the sql file is executed by root user.
Are you accessing it with root or some other user? if another user then it might be  a permission issue?

Comment: Ok, but I login in Workbench also as root user. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

In the `volumes` you are missing a `/`, the correct syntax will be:

```
volumes:
  - ./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

What is happening is, the content inside the folder is not getting copied, instead a folder is made inside the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. To ensure it is present in correct place, look inside the container by using `docker exec`.

Comment: ```- ./mysql-initdb/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d``` in my case still does not help.

Comment: Can you show me the output after you tried this, because in my case, it was working perfectly well.

Comment: The issue is probably related with MEMORY engine. After switching to InnoDB it works.

Comment: That's great then! If you have solved it then write your answer! I hope it would help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  Mysql wasn't populating the tables.  Mysql was defined as a Docker volume and the import sql was bind mounted.  These definitions were fine.  I dug a little bit more and found that I had MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD set in my environment.  I was also trying to run some sql in a file called 0users.sql inside the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory.  That file was attempting to RECREATE the user defined in MYSQL_USER environment variable.  I removed the 2 environment variables.  Then, I removed the Docker container and mysql volume.  Then, tried again.  Worked.

My assumption is that if the container runs into any kind of SQL error, the entire import appears to stop.  Since my file was at the top of the alphabetical order, the import died on user creation and no tables were imported.